# Why Angular AJAX request is visible twice in chrome network tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I just noticed that when I made Angular (**1.4.8**) AJAX POST request it is visible twice in chrome network tab (first (355B) as `angular.js:10765` and second (812B) as `other` where first looks like request and second as response - only second contains response data).
I made identical request by use of jQuery and it's appearing as a single request (812B).

CODE:

```
return function ( id ) {
  var deferred = $q.defer()
    , data = {
      id: id || null,
      range: tbDateRange.get( true )
    }
    ;

  /* TODO - REMOVE */
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: path,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: data
  });

  $http.post( path, data )
    .success( function ( data ) {
      /*...*/
      deferred.resolve( data );
    } )
    .error( function ( error ) {
      /*...*/
    } );
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

And network tab screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular defaults to POSTing JSON formatted data instead of form encoded data (jQuery does not so the statement *I made identical request by use of jQuery* is incorrect).

Cross-origin, JSON formatted, POST requests require a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Presumably (because you haven't show any details of the requests besides the end of the URL they are going to), the first of those requests is that preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: Yes that is all correct I found `Request Method:OPTIONS` in headers. Thanks.